# Setting a Window's Minimum and Maximum Size using WINAPI

Tags: c, winapi

How can I make it so my window never gets any smaller than x,y? Which WINAPI function can do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You reply to [WM_GETMINMAXINFO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632626%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and fill in the structure with your limits.

Answer (score 3):

You can do that by handling [`WM_GETMINMAXINFO`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms632626%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) & modifying `MINMAXINFO`.