# QT - Lost keyboard control when embedding application into QApplication

Tags: windows, qt, keyboard, embed

I'm using Qt 5.2 and trying to embed notepad.exe into a widget in my QApplication.
 my code is:

```
    HWND winHandle = ::FindWindowA(NULL, "Untitled - Notepad");
    if(winHandle != NULL)
    {
        QWindow * window = QWindow::fromWinId((WId) winHandle);
        QWidget * notepadWidget = QWidget::createWindowContainer(window);
        notepadWidget ->setParent( ui->widget);
        QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout();
        layout->addWidget(notepadWidget);
        ui->widget->setLayout(layout);
     }
```

the notepad window is embedded beautifully into my application, but i **lost the keyboard**! i cannot type inside notepad. the mouse is working properly(i can select text, etc.)
anyone?

Comment: possible duplicate of [GUI freeze when using Windows::SetParent on QApplication](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24116335/gui-freeze-when-using-windowssetparent-on-qapplication)

Comment: You've already asked that question.

Comment: You are right, but since from the answers there the question changed - i'm not anymore asking about a GUI freeze of the parent application, i thought to open a new thread.