# How to set window max size using window handle

Tags: c#, api, window, max, size

What is the equivalent windows api function to..

```
this.MaximumSize = new Size(500, 500);
```

on winforms? (I have only the handle of form)

This link [How do I change another program's window's size?](http://How%20do%20I%20change%20another%20program's%20window's%20size?)

does not solves how to set maximum size of window, it addresses size of window.

Comment: _I have only the handle of form_ Does the form belong to your application or to a 3rd-party program?

Comment: Ahmed Abdelhameed the handle belongs to another programs opened on desktop.

Comment: You need to send a `WM_GETMINMAXINFO` message to the window. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winmsg/wm-getminmaxinfo

Comment: Gusman, I tried through your link and this is what I could find so far;  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794630/setting-a-windows-minimum-and-maximum-size-using-winapi  but it replies back withing form to return maximum size values. I'm having only the handle of window as reference. How to call the outside program window with WM_GETMINMAXINFO  through my program?